# Contraction of Bellman Operator under general $L_p$ norms

Tags: probability, convex-analysis, control-theory, jensen-inequality, contraction-operator

We know that the Bellman Operator
$$
TV(s) = \max_a r(s,a) + \sum_{s' \in S}p(s'|s,a)V(s')
$$
is a contraction under $L_\infty$ norm.For reference one can see the following link [Proof that Bellman update is a contraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453973/proof-that-bellman-update-is-a-contraction)
A couple of definitions are warranted:
$p(s'|s,a)$ is the probability of hitting state $s'$ under action $a$ at state $s$. $S$ is the set of all possible states. $r(s,a)$ is the reward, incurred at state $s$ when playing action $a$. $V(s')$ is the reward incuured at state $s'$ over an entire horizon when optimal actions are chosen at each subsequent state. 
I was wondering what was stopping it from being a contraction in any $L_p$ norm. Ofcourse in finite dimensions it should not be a problem because all norms are equivalent in finite dimensions, so I guess the only interesting thing is in infinite dimensions.
My idea is that
$$
\begin{split}\|TV - T\bar{V}\|_p& = \bigg(\sum_s\big(\sum_{s'}p(s'|s,a^*)(V(s')-\bar{V}(s'))\big)^p\bigg)^{1/p}\\
&\leq \sum_{s'}p(s'|s,a^*)\bigg(\sum_s\bigg(V(s')-\bar{V}(s')\bigg)^p\bigg)^{1/p}
\end{split}$$ by Jensen Inequality
and then $\sum_{s'}p(s'|s,a) = 1$
to get
$$
\|TV - T\bar{V}\|_p \leq \|V - \bar{V}\|_p.
$$
What is the mistake?

Comment: You have to add some definitions here: what are $r$, $p(s'\vert s,a)$ and $S$?

Comment: I think I used the well agreed upon notation as used in control theory with bellman equation. For reference on definitions @https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453973/proof-that-bellman-update-is-a-contraction provides a nice reference. I believe for this purpose only relevant definition is $p(s'|s,a)$ is a conditional probability over a contable set $S$. One can even forget $r$ and $a$ but for curiosity $a$ referers to an action $s$ refers to a state of a dynamical system and $r$ refers to a cost/utility incurred when applyting action $a$ at state $s$.

Comment: $V(s)$ represents the cost associated with a particular state when optimal actions are played on it.

Comment: You shall definitively define these objects in your question, even though some of them could be obvious. The reader must understand everything from you text and not from the title, tags and/or links to other questions. This would enhance the quality of your question.

Comment: Sure.. would do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found my error. My definition of Jensen's was wrong.

The correct inequality would be in terms of $L_2$ norm

$$\|TV - T\bar{V}\|_2 \leq \sqrt{|S|}\|V-\bar{V}\|_2$$
and hence obviously cannot be a contraction even in finite dimensions